# Can't make more than one request on java.net.http.HttpClient or will receive: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, exception, httprequest, sslhandshakeexception, java-http-client

I was testing out the new `HttpClient` from Java 11 and came across the following behaviour:

I am making two Async requests to a public REST API for testing and tried it with one client and two separate requests. This process didn't throw any exceptions.

```java
String singleCommentUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/1";
String commentsUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments";

Consumer<String> handleOneComment = s -> {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Comment comment = gson.fromJson(s, Comment.class);
    System.out.println(comment);
};
Consumer<String> handleListOfComments = s -> {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Comment[] comments = gson.fromJson(s, Comment[].class);
    List<Comment> commentList = Arrays.asList(comments);
    commentList.forEach(System.out::println);
};

HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();

client.sendAsync(HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create(singleCommentUrl)).build(), HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
        .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
        .thenAccept(handleOneComment)
        .join();

client.sendAsync(HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create(commentsUrl)).build(), HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
        .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
        .thenAccept(handleListOfComments)
        .join();
```

Then I tried refactoring the `HttpClient` into a method and I got the following exception when it tried to make the second request:

```java
public void run() {
    String singleCommentUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/1";
    String commentsUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments";

    Consumer<String> handleOneComment = s -> {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Comment comment = gson.fromJson(s, Comment.class);
        System.out.println(comment);
    };
    Consumer<String> handleListOfComments = s -> {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Comment[] comments = gson.fromJson(s, Comment[].class);
        List<Comment> commentList = Arrays.asList(comments);
        commentList.forEach(System.out::println);
    };

    sendRequest(handleOneComment, singleCommentUrl);
    sendRequest(handleListOfComments, commentsUrl);
}

private void sendRequest(Consumer<String> onSucces, String url) {
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create(url)).build();

    client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
            .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
            .thenAccept(onSucces)
            .join();
}
```

This produces the following exception after succesfully executing the first request and failing at the second one:

```sh
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeRelay(CompletableFuture.java:367)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeRelay(CompletableFuture.java:376)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1074)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate.handleError(SSLFlowDelegate.java:904)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader.processData(SSLFlowDelegate.java:450)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader$ReaderDownstreamPusher.run(SSLFlowDelegate.java:263)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SynchronizedRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:175)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:147)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:198)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:128)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:279)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:181)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.decode(SSLEngineImpl.java:672)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:627)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:422)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:634)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader.unwrapBuffer(SSLFlowDelegate.java:480)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader.processData(SSLFlowDelegate.java:389)
    ... 7 more
```

I tried passing separate clients and requests via parameters in the method as well but it produced the same result. What is going on here?

Comment: Is there a reason why your application can't hold onto a single `HttpClient` instance and use that for all requests? (At least, all requests which require the same `HttpClient` settings.)

Comment: Not really, that would be the desired behaviour. I was just testing out the new HttpClient from java 11 and came across this. If it was an actual application I would use a single HttpClient as a service most likely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, [SSLContext](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html) objects are not thread-safe.  (It’s usually correct to assume that any mutable object whose contract doesn’t explicitly guarantee thread safety is not thread-safe.)

HttpClients [use the default SSLContext](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.Builder.html#sslContext(javax.net.ssl.SSLContext)) if not given a context explicitly.  So it appears your two requests are trying to simultaneously share that default context.

The solution is to specify a brand new SSLContext for each HttpClient:

```
private void sendRequest(Consumer<String> onSucces, String url) {
    SSLContext context;
    try {
        context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.3");
        context.init(null, null, null);
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().sslContext(context).build();
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create(url)).build();

    client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
            .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
            .thenAccept(onSucces)
            .join();
}
```

Comment: Have you tested `init` in a thread-safe context and then use the client in concurrent context? It could be only the `init` method which is unsafe? I got a problem problem related to unsafe `init` when use by several threads [JDK-8197807](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8197807).

Comment: @NicolasHenneaux I’m not sure what you mean.  In the above code, the use of `init` is thread-safe, since the SSLContext is not visible to any other methods or threads.  Are you talking about invoking `init` on the default SSLContext?

Comment: Doing twice `sendAsync` calls as in the question and see if it works?

Comment: @NicolasHenneaux It seems to work when I try it.  Which is what I would expect, since I would expect the HttpClient to read the state of the SSLContext but not modify it.

Comment: I was expecting the same but great you were able to confirm !